# Brace-mismatch error recognition in Texstudio?

Tags: texstudio

I've been trying to find in Texstudio the ability in Texlipse in recognizing brace matching errors, but no success so far.

In Texlipse whenever a single brace is in your document a red line is drawn underneath it which decreases error handling time. Take this little code for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  a &= 1\frac{3}{2}}\\ % "}" after {2} is extra
  b &= 2\frac{3}{4}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

In Texstudio you can only become aware of the error, if the cursor is placed after or befor the brace. Is there such an option in it? Is it manually possible to add this capability to it?

Answer (score 6):

As you noted, automatic brace-matching detection is currently only possible within the context of the cursor. However, you can manually trigger a search for a mismatch by `Idefix -> Parenthesis -> Find Mismatch`. The default keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl+Shift+P,M`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is one step forward. Manually, the mismatching brace can only be detected if the cursor is before the line.

Comment: What is `Idefix`?

Comment: It's the menu name. I don't really know where that comes from. One explaination is that it's the name of the dog of Obelix (well not in English, but in a number of other languages). So it could be someting like "Little Helpers".

Comment: Everything aside, is a missing "(" or ")" a reason for error in TexStudio?